# Connecting React to index.html to test npm package

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to connect my react code (javascript) to index.html and it's not working.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {

  return (
    <div>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

HTML

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">

            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
            <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
           
        </head>
    
        <body>
            <div id="root"></div>
          
            <script type="text/babel" src="App.js" ></script>
          
        </body>

    </html>
```

Can't figure out why index.html is blank. The reason I'm trying to connect the two is to implement react components from the source code (git cloned) of a npm module I downloaded. I'm new to coding and figured this would be helpful to "debug" and learn that codebase. Any advice on that front would be extremely helpful as well.

Comment: After cloning that repository, did you `cd` into it and install the dependencies (`npm install`), then "start" the project (`npm start`)?

Comment: Yes, but I’m trying to build an “interface” for the code via an index.html page and an App.js - so I could debug the code to understand it better. Does that sound like it makes sense?

Comment: I guess it isn't clear what you mean by "build an interface". Other than including React via CDN this appears to be the standard way to render a react application. Unless you've changed the package scripts it should be running on `http://localhost:3000/` when you run the start script. Are there any errors in your terminal when you start the app? Any errors/logging in the browser's console? Do you see you app rendered into the DOM (use the web inspector)?